# Trying to build a project which uses the libcurl library - cannot find -lbrotlidec

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl, msys2

I am trying to build a project which uses `libcurl`. It finds all of the dependencies, except one - `-lbrotlidec`:

```
D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lbrotlidec
```

I have the `mingw-w64-x86_64-brotli` package installed. I ran

```
ld --verbose -lbrotlidec
```

and `ld` did find the library.

```
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/brotlidec.dll.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/brotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libbrotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libbrotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/brotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.dll.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/brotlidec.dll.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/brotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib/brotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/mingw64/lib\libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/libbrotlidec.dll.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/brotlidec.dll.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/brotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/libbrotlidec.lib failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/libbrotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib/brotlidec.dll failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/usr/local/lib\libbrotlidec.a failed
attempt to open d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.dll.a succeeded
d:\msys64\mingw64\bin\../../mingw64/lib/libbrotlidec.dll.a
```

How should I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Does this file: `d:\msys64\mingw64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libbrotlidec.dll.a` exist? Note the 2 mingw64 folders. When I look at my mingw64 installed on my c: I don't have a mingw64 folder inside a mingw64 folder containing a `x86_64-w64-mingw32` folder. I just have `c:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Comment: It does exist. I entered the path into File Explorer.

Comment: I suspect the `curl` Makefile attempts to use `pkg-config` to locate `libbrotlidec` which is failing due to no package config files for `libbrotlidec` under MinGW (or somehting similar) Double-check what can't find the library, `pkg-config` or `ld`. Another possibility is that `libbrotlidec` does provide package config files, but the location or naming for its `pkg-config` files under MinGW for `libbrotlidec` are wrong (I have had that happen before too) Generally this type thing is relatively easy to fix, but you have to nail down exactly what needs fixing.

Comment: Both `pkg-config` and `ld` can find the library.